# Spring/J2EE : get an entity and its children

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I want to load an entity with the set of its nested entities.
Here is how I do :

Entity Father

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "father")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@chilId")
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
```

Entity Child

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@fatherId")
    private Father father;
```

In a Spring MVC Rest controller I am loading a Father.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fathers/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ResponseEntity<Father> getLot(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Father father = fatherRepository.findOne(id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(father)
            .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
                result,
                HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

After `Father father = fatherRepository.findOne(id);` if I debug father, I am getting its children, it's ok.

But then if I add a child in my database (in another spring controller) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/children",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Child> createStock(@RequestBody Child child) throws URISyntaxException {
        if (child.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert("child", "idexists", "A new child cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
        }
        Child result = stockRepository.save(child);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/stocks/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("child", result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

And if then I load a father entity, I am not getting the new child I have created for this father.
I think there is something to do with @transactionnal annotation, but I don't see what.

[UPDATE]
I have managed to get what I want.
Doing like below works :

```
Father father = ownerRepository.findOne(id);
Child child= new Car();
child.setFather(father);
child = carrepository.save(child);
father.getChildren().add(child);
father = ownerRepository.save(father);
father = ownerRepository.findOne(id);
```

If I do that :

```
Father father = ownerRepository.findOne(id);
Child child= new Car();
child.setFather(father);
child = carrepository.save(child);
father = ownerRepository.findOne(id);
```

I don't get the new child in father object when I retrieve the father after having saved the child.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the transaction is not commited or flushed

Have a look on : @EnableTransactionManagement tells Spring that classes with the @Transactional annotation should be wrapped with the Transactional Aspect. With this the @Transactional is now ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FetchType.EAGER with father entity. So this will load the child when you will fetch father entity. Hope this helps you!

Comment: with Fetch.EAGER, I am getting the same problem. I don't see the new child I have created in the list of children of the father. I need to restart the server to see him.

Comment: From the code you have pasted above I understood that it is saving the child objects individually but not able to return the same. Correct me if I am wrong. And if you can paste the code where you saving the child(save code which is usually we write in DAOImpl) from different controller I hope that will help me to find out the problem.

Comment: Create a fresh Father object( e.g Father  updatedFather = ownerRepository.findOne(id);) then get it from DB and return the same!